# How to define context object for graphql subscription server

Tags: graphql, graphql-subscriptions

With the normal graphql server we can define the context object like this:

```
app.use('/graphql', graphqlExpress(async (req) => {
    return {
      schema,
      context: {
        app,
        params,
      }
    };
  }));
```

** subscription server **

How can I do the same for the subscription server? (Doing the hybrid http / websocket approach). Can't seem to find a solution from the docs.

```
new SubscriptionServer({
    execute,
    subscribe,
    schema,
    onConnect: (connectionParams, webSocket) => {
      console.log(connectionParams);
    }
  }, {
    server,
    path: '/subscriptions'
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a middleware before the `execute` function and add the required context before resolving the subscription.

It could look like this:

```html
const middleware = (args) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const [schema, document, root, context, variables, operation] = args;
      
      context.app = <your app parameter>;
      context.params = <your params>;
      
      resolve(args);
});


SubscriptionServer.create({
  schema,
  subscribe,
  execute: (...args) => middleware(args).then(args => { return execute(...args); }) },
  {
    server: httpServer,
    path: "/subscription",
  },
);
```

As you can see you have all the data from the request in the args of the `execute` function.